# PyQt send parameters with button click

Tags: python, pyqt

I have a GUI that has 4 widgets which are user inputs (file in/out and directory in/out). I am trying to make a button that will do two things.

1. I want to button when clicked to send the four user set parameters to another imported function.

   ```
       self.btn.clicked.connect(lambda: self.sendData(self.rawName, self.outName, self.directoryIn, self.directoryOut))
   ```

I was using something like this. Where send data looks like this:

```
def sendData(self, rawName, outName, directoryIn, directoryOut):
    try:
        foo.main(rawName, outName, directoryIn, directoryOut)
    except TypeError:
        pass
```

In this case foo.main is the imported function. The user input method looks like this:

```
   def setInputDirectory(self):
       options = QtGui.QFileDialog.DontResolveSymlinks | QtGui.QFileDialog.ShowDirsOnly
       directoryIn = QtGui.QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(self,
                                                       "Some Directory",
                                                       self.directoryLabelIn.text(), options)
       if directoryIn:
           self.directoryLabelIn.setText(directoryIn)
```

Finally, I want to have the button (btn) be clickable only when all four values are entered in the gui.

Answer (score 1):

```
self.rawName = ""
self.outName = ""
self.directoryIn = ""
self.directoryOut = ""
...
self.btn.clicked.connect(self.sendData)
self.btn.setEnabled(False) # disable button here, enable it later
```

so you can simply send those parameters directly:

```
def sendData(self):
    try:
        foo.main(self.rawName, self.outName, self.directoryIn, self.directoryOut)
    except TypeError:
        pass
```

also after every input, check if all four values are entered and if so enable button:

```
def areAllFourValuesEntered(self):
    if (self.rawName!="" and self.outName!="" and self.directoryIn!="" and self.directoryOut!=""):
        self.btn.setEnabled(True)
```

Comment: Hmm, I does not seem to pass the values. Do I need to change the setInputDirectory method? It seems like the self.whatever is still = ""

Comment: oh, you need to pass it to SELF.whatever, like this: `self.directoryIn = QtGui.QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory....`. In your case `directoryIn` is local attribute in method `setInputDirectory` and it is destroyed at the exit of method scope. On the other side, any attribute that has `self.attName` is visible anywhere in class scope.